# ffmpeg filename output format

Tags: ffmpeg

When using `ffmpeg` to output a series of frames as images, [the only format I can find documentation for](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#image2-1) is `frame_%d.jpg`. The `%d` identifier is replaced by the sequential frame count.

Are there other parameters I can use in the output file format? Specifically, I need the ability to add the timestamp of the specific frame.

Comment: Also taking this up with ffmpeg-dev - http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2011-December/117790.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out this behavior was not yet implemented at the time.

I implemented an initial version of `%t` support on my fork of FFmpeg (https://github.com/yuvadm/FFmpeg), and am currently working on cleaning up the patch so that it can be merged upstream.

Comment: Did you ever submit this to the core project? There's an [open 3yr-old request](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1452) (that I found while trying to do this myself).

Comment: @YuvalAdam take a look to [your ffmpeg repo on github](https://github.com/yuvadm/FFmpeg/commit/e1524dda42c9056f393a0ec0eb494d5dc31e2b1e#commitcomment-19635439) please. :)

Comment: @florida I've added an updated patch to https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1452 which is Works on My Machine™ certified since I was searching for this functionality.

Answer (score 8):

[The `strftime` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Examples) allows you to expand the filename with date and time information. Check [the documentation of the strftime() function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) for the syntax.

For example to generate image files from the strftime() `%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S` pattern, the following ffmpeg command can be used:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -r 1 -i /dev/video0 -f image2 -strftime 1 "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.jpg"
```

Comment: As far as I understand, this will output the actual time and date, while my requirement is for the running time of the video.

Comment: Unfortunately only "second" granularity (gives wall clock time) but it does work...

Comment: For those of us on Ubuntu 14 who a forced to use avconv the strftime option is not available for segmentation.  I couldn't find a workaround, but was able to install FFMPEG on ubuntu 14 by doing
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
`sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

Answer (score 2):

I hacked up a bash script that creates file names based on time into the film.  It uses a format: "hh_mm_ss" in the file name.  You can see it at:

https://github.com/pozar/makemoviethumbs

Comment: Appears to require "constant" frame rate, which unfortunately I do not have :|

Answer (score 1):

Another option you'd have would be to run ffprobe -show_packets on it, and use that data to "infer" the timestamp of each generated jpg file (assuming you generate one per incoming video frame). Yikes!

Answer (score 0):

For number of frames can use report with special debug mode:

```
FFREPORT=file=\'file.log\':level=48 && ffmpeg ... -vf select=eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I) -vsync vfr -f image2 OUTPUT
```

then you can match the name with `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all("/] n:(\\d+)\\.[^>]+pict_type:I/Us",$log,$m,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER,5000);
$frames=$m[1];
```

Please enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can try **%s** with **-strftime** if you want to attach epoch.

Example :

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i 'input.mp4' -vf fps=1 -strftime 1 "%s_frame.png"
```