# Output for ffmpeg

Tags: ubuntu, time, ffmpeg, timestamp, output

Hello is there a way to output a saved image filename in a format such as yyyy-mm-dd_hrs:min:seconds_imagenumber? ie (img 2018-07-07_17:34:22_001). And the command has to include fps so that we are able to tweak the fps accordingly. The command also has to churn out images every second. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -vf fps=1 img_`date +%F_%T`_%03d.png -hide_banner
```

Comment: Thanks! However, the timing of the saved file appears to be static. ie (img_2018-07-19_13:55:18_001.png) and (img_2018-07-19_13:55:18_002.png) I want the timing to increase by 1 second for each image since fps = 1

Comment: Looks like [this would do this job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544816/ffmpeg-filename-output-format).

Comment: I cant seem to find a solution. Is there any other command that will ouput the number sequencing of each image as well as the real time the images is produced?