# How to add the timestamp as a part of the generated image file name in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, filenames

I am trying to extract png images from a video using ffmpeg and add the timestamp as a part of the generated image file name.

Please see the below command I am using for the same

```
ffmpeg -vcodec mpeg2video -f mpegts -i test_movie.ts -f image2 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/Library/Fonts/Tahoma.ttf: timecode='$(date +%H\\:%M\\:%S).00': r=30: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1" -vsync vfr -pattern_type glob ./compare_multiple_$(gdate +%H\_%M\_%S_%3N).png
```

But this is not appending the filename properly. It gives an error as shown below:

> [image2 @ 0x7ff01301f600] Could not get frame filename number 2 from
>   pattern './compare_multiple_10_09_58_490.png' (either set updatefirst
>   or use a pattern like %03d within the filename pattern)
>   av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument frame=   10 fps=0.0
>   q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.12 bitrate=N/A video:1047kB audio:0kB
>   subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead:
>   unknown Conversion failed!

Comment: I agree.. Can be voted to close or delete.

Answer (score 3):

For the output filename pattern you can use:

```
ffmpeg -i ... -f image2 -strftime 1 "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.png"
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to generate a file on every frame, that is 30 frames in a second, with the millisecond as a value in the filename.

Comment: It doesn't have the necessary resolution.